# Asynchronous operations within an asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading, apartments

My multi-threading knowledge is still pretty rudimentary, so would really appreciate some pointers here. I have an interface, IOperationInvoker (from WCF) which has the following methods:

```
IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
```

Given a concrete implementation of this interface, I need to implement the same interface, whilst calling the underlying implementation in a seperate Thread. (in case you're wondering why, the concrete implmentation calls a legacy COM object which needs to be in a different apartment state).

At the moment, I'm doing something like this:

```
public StaOperationSyncInvoker : IOperationInvoker {
   IOperationInvoker _innerInvoker;
   public StaOperationSyncInvoker(IOperationInvoker invoker) {
       this._innerInvoker = invoker;
   } 


    public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(BeginInvokeDelegate);
        InvokeDelegateArgs ida = new InvokeDelegateArgs(_innerInvoker, instance, inputs, callback, state);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start(ida);
        // would do t.Join() if doing syncronously
        // how to wait to get IAsyncResult?
        return ida.AsyncResult;
    }

    public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // how to call invoke end on the 
        // thread? could we have wrapped IAsyncResult
        // to get a reference here?
        return null;
    }

    private class InvokeDelegateArgs {
        public InvokeDelegateArgs(IOperationInvoker invoker, object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            this.Invoker = invoker;
            this.Instance = instance;
            this.Inputs = inputs;
            this.Callback = callback;
            this.State = state;
        }

        public IOperationInvoker Invoker { get; private set; }
        public object Instance { get; private set; }
        public AsyncCallback Callback { get; private set; }
        public IAsyncResult AsyncResult { get; set; }
        public Object[] Inputs { get; private set; }
        public Object State { get; private set; }
    }
    private static void BeginInvokeDelegate(object data)
    {
        InvokeDelegateArgs ida = (InvokeDelegateArgs)data;
        ida.AsyncResult = ida.Invoker.InvokeBegin(ida.Instance, ida.Inputs, ida.Callback, ida.State);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I need to wrap up the returned AsyncResult with my own, so I can get back to the thread we've spooled up... but honestly I'm a little out of my depth. Any pointers?

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement a synchronous method asynchronously is to put it into a delegate, and use the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` methods on the resulting delegate. This will run the synchronous method on a threadpool thread, and `BeginInvoke` will return an `IAsyncResult` implementation, so you don't have to implement the guts of it. However, you do need to smuggle a little extra data into the `IAsyncResult` returned by `IOperationInvoker.InvokeEnd`. You could do that easily by creating an implementation of `IAsyncResult` that delegates everything to an inner `IAsyncResult`, but has an extra field to contain the delegate, so that when the `IAsyncResult` instance is passed to `InvokeEnd`, you can access the delegate to call `EndInvoke` on it.

However, after closer reading of your question, I see that you need to use an explicit thread with COM settings etc.

What you need to do is properly implement `IAsyncResult`. Almost everything follows from this, since the `IAsyncResult` will contain all the bits needed for synchronization.

Here's a very simple, but not terribly efficient, implementation of `IAsyncResult`. It encapsulates all the essential features: passing arguments, a synchronization event, callback implementation, propagating exceptions from async task and returning result.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class MyAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    object _state;
    object _lock = new object();
    ManualResetEvent _doneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    AsyncCallback _callback;
    Exception _ex;
    bool _done;
    int _result;
    int _x;

    public MyAsyncResult(int x, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _state = state;
        _x = x; // arbitrary argument(s)
    }

    public int X { get { return _x; } }

    public void SignalDone(int result)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _result = result;
            _done = true;
            _doneEvent.Set();
        }
        // never invoke any delegate while holding a lock
        if (_callback != null)
            _callback(this); 
    }

    public void SignalException(Exception ex)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _ex = ex;
            _done = true;
            _doneEvent.Set();
        }
        if (_callback != null)
            _callback(this);
    }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return _state; }
    }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { return _doneEvent; }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public int Result
    {
        // lock (or volatile, complex to explain) needed
        // for memory model problems.
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_ex != null)
                    throw _ex;
                return _result;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { lock (_lock) return _done; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void MyTask(object param)
    {
        MyAsyncResult ar = (MyAsyncResult) param;
        try
        {
            int x = ar.X;
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulate lengthy work
            ar.SignalDone(x * 2); // demo work = double X
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ar.SignalException(ex);
        }
    }

    static IAsyncResult Begin(int x, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(MyTask);
        MyAsyncResult ar = new MyAsyncResult(x, callback, state);
        th.Start(ar);
        return ar;
    }

    static int End(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        MyAsyncResult mar = (MyAsyncResult) ar;
        mar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        return mar.Result; // will throw exception if one 
                           // occurred in background task
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // demo calling code
        // we don't need state or callback for demo
        IAsyncResult ar = Begin(42, null, null); 
        int result = End(ar);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It's important for correctness that client code can't see the `IAsyncResult` implementation, otherwise they might access methods like `SignalException` inappropriately or read `Result` prematurely. The class can be made more efficient by not constructing the `WaitHandle` implementation (`ManualResetEvent` in the example) if it's not necessary, but this is tricky to get 100% right. Also, the `Thread` and `ManualResetEvent` can and should be disposed of in the `End` implementation, as should be done with all objects that implement `IDisposable`. And obviously, `End` should check to make sure that it has gotten an implementation of the right class to get a nicer exception than a cast exception. I've left these and other details out as they obscure the essential mechanics of the async implementation.